# Reduce returns undefined with condition

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I have a string that a parse to a JSON object. Now i want to check for every object key if it contains a certain sub string. In that case I want to add it to my accumulated object. Somehow i keep getting undefined.

Here's the code :

```
const myString = '{ "Address__c": "3QAO", "Id": "OxWQAU", "Address__r": { "Address_Line_1__c": "kjj", "Address_Line_2__c": "kl", "Country__c": "United States", "State__c": "California", "Id": "a022M00001aJIW3QAO", "CountryLabel": "United States", "StateLabel": "California" } }';

const parsed = JSON.parse(myString);
const nameSpace = 'NameSpace__';

const newObj = Object.keys(parsed).reduce((acc,curr) => {

    if(curr.includes('__c')){
        return {...acc , [nameSpace + curr] : parsed[curr]};
    }


},{})

console.log(newObj)
```

EDIT:

So adding an else gives me the following result :

```
{ NameSpace__Address__c: '3QAO' }
```

How can it be that just one key is altered. When there's more than 1 containing this '__c' string

Comment: If the `if` is not fulfilled, nothing will be returned, so the accumulator will be `undefined` on the next iteration...

Comment: How can it not be fullfilled, my keys do contain the '__c' , or am i doing something wrong? @CertainPerformance

Comment: @Kevin.a, you have to return the acc on each step (changed or not) to continue to work with it on the next step. In case a current element does NOT include your String you will drop your accumulator, that's why you get nothing at the very end.

Comment: `Address__c` is the only key in `parsed` that satisfies the `if` condition. That's why you get only one key in the output. Do you need other keys like `Id` in the output as well? Do you also need to replace the nested keys like `Address_Line_1__c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides adding `else { return acc }`, there is a reason your result only includes a single key.

Your `parsed` object is:

```
{ Address__c: '3QAO',
  Id: 'OxWQAU',
  Address__r: 
   { Address_Line_1__c: 'kjj',
     Address_Line_2__c: 'kl',
     Country__c: 'United States',
     State__c: 'California',
     Id: 'a022M00001aJIW3QAO',
     CountryLabel: 'United States',
     StateLabel: 'California' } }
```

So that means `Object.keys(parsed)` is:

```
[ 'Address__c', 'Id', 'Address__r' ]
```

So those are your possible `curr` values.

From here you can go either with a recursive approach if you want to add the nested keys too or you flatten the structure beforehand.

A unclean recursive solution would look something like:

```js
const myString = '{ "Address__c": "3QAO", "Id": "OxWQAU", "Address__r": { "Address_Line_1__c": "kjj", "Address_Line_2__c": "kl", "Country__c": "United States", "State__c": "California", "Id": "a022M00001aJIW3QAO", "CountryLabel": "United States", "StateLabel": "California" } }';

const parsed = JSON.parse(myString);
const nameSpace = 'NameSpace__';

const newObj = parsed => Object.keys(parsed).reduce((acc,curr) => {

    if (parsed[curr] instanceof Object) {
      return {...acc, ...newObj(parsed[curr])}
    }
    
    if(curr.includes('__c')) {
        return {...acc , [nameSpace + curr] : parsed[curr]};
    } else {
      return acc;
    }

},{})

console.log("result: ", newObj(parsed))
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah! maybe adding `else { return acc }`

Answer (score 0):

Reduce function gives you only one object (for example sum of every objects), you should use 'filter' to get list of your wanted objects.